# Add motion blur to navbar text when Bootstrap carousel sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the problem when the bootstrap carousel changes the image, it's adds the class next ( `transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);` ) for item and Add motion blur during the effect to text my navbar menu.. 
[image]

You can see example here: http://bek.2d.uz/ Please look the navbar maximum 10 sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this fix:

```
.main_menu .navbar .navbar-nav {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

translateZ(0) hack forces the browser to create a new layer and send rendering to the GPU.

Comment: Niceee... Thank you bro))